# Как передать данные из одно фильтра в другой. Java Jersy 2

Tags: java, jersey

Есть фильтр 1
В нем я проверяю есть ли нужный параметр в header.
Если нет, то прерываю, если есть то хочу передать этот параметр в следующий фильтр.
Далее фильтр 2
В нем я беру этот параметр и стучусь в базу.

Как передать параметр? Не хотелось бы в каждом фильтре лезть в header, расшифровывать и т.д.

```js
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
    if (headers.get("token") == null) {
      requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).build());
    }
  }
```

Это фильтр 1. Как мне в блок `else` передать token. И принять его в следующем фильтре?

Answer (score 0):

А где какое "расшифровывание" происходит? Все заголовки уже находятся в `requestContext.getHeader()`, и повторное обращение к нужному заголовку практически никаких накладных расходов не несёт.

Можно полученный `token` сохранить в свойстве запроса с помощью [метода](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) `requestContext.setProperty()`.

> Как мне в блок else передать token.

Присвоить значение заголовка какой-нибудь переменной:

```
 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
   String token = headers.get("token");
   if (token == null) {
     requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(401).build());
   } else {
     // or else
   }
 }
```

Но на мой вгляд гораздо правильнее будет объединить фильтры и проверять наличие `token` во втором фильтре.